# Uso dell'oggettiva col verbo "esprimere"

Tags: verbs

Mi chiedo se *esprimere* possa reggere l'oggettiva. Altri verbi che ricadono nella stessa classe semantica lo fanno senza problemi:

```
Dico che quella casa è lontana
Proclamo che il lavoro è difficile
```

*Esprimere* non mi sembra suonare bene con l'oggettiva, ma non ho una spiegazione. Vorrei sapere se è accettabile nel linguaggio scritto, se è un errore o meno.

Comment: Sarò io che la faccio troppo facile, ma il verbo è transitivo, quindi che problemi dovrebbero esserci?

Comment: anche "proclamare" e "dire" sono transitivi, non mi pare che sia questo il motivo.

Comment: Voglio dire semplicemente che se il verbo è transitivo, non vedo nessuna ragione per cui non possa avere una oggettiva.

Comment: @karoshi Quindi a te suona bene "esprimo che va bene"?

Comment: A me suona bene, naturalmente se poi a te non piace nessuno ti obbliga ad usarlo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Etimologicamente “esprimere” significa “premere fuori”, ma, usato nel comune senso di «Manifestare con parole, a voce o in scritto, i proprî pensieri o sentimenti: *gli ho espresso le mie idee in proposito*; *e. il proprio parere*» (Treccani), non c'è motivo per cui non si possa costruire con un'oggettiva. E infatti in Google Books, pescando un po' a caso, si trovano esempi come:

- «Se voi con tali vocaboli intendete esprimere che cotesti beni appartennero un tempo a qualche individuo della nazione, il fatto è vero, ma falsa la conclusione che se ne suol dedurre...» (Gabriele De Rosa, Luigi Taparelli d'Azeglio)
- «... chi segue tale via deve trovare un qualche modo per esprimere che la legge da lui accettata ... soddisfa alla condizione sopra accennata» (Vilfredo Pareto)
- «...per esprimere che a va moltiplicato per b si scrive ab, od anche a.b...» (Enrico Garnier)

ma, soprattutto, il Tommaseo alla voce “[esprimere](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items/44293)” esemplifica tra l'altro con «Si vuol esprimere che giacciono tutti oppressi non solo dalle tenebre, ma anche dal sonno».

Comment: Magnifica, esaustiva e dettagliata risposta.

Comment: Grazie per il link, @FerdinandBardamu !

Comment: Di nulla. :-) Ho scoperto per caso come fare: basta marcare un lemma come preferito, andare alla sezione preferiti, cliccare sul preferito appena inserito, e s’otterrà il collegamento diretto. Magari c’è un modo meno macchinoso, ma questo intanto funziona…